# Where should I release the group queue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch

I have this in my code:

```
- (void)loadPanoramaForLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
...
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self getImageForPanorama:model level:level face:PLCubeFaceOrientationFront completion:^(PLImage * image) {
        if (image) {
            [cubicPanorama setTexture:[PLTexture textureWithImage:image] face: PLCubeFaceOrientationFront];
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }
    }];
...
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self getImageForPanorama:model level:level face:PLCubeFaceOrientationBack completion:^(PLImage * image) {
        if (image) {
            [cubicPanorama setTexture:[PLTexture textureWithImage:image] face: PLCubeFaceOrientationBack];
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }
    }];
...
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        dispatch_release(group);
        NSObject<PLIPanorama> *panorama = cubicPanorama;
        [plView setPanorama:panorama];
    });
}
```

I don't use ARC in this code and I want to know, is it the correct way to use `dispatch_release` here? Where should I put it? Is it ok to put it in `dispatch_group_notify`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can release it as the last thing in `-loadPanoramaForLocation:`. `dispatch_group_notify()` is documented to retain it until the notification block has run to completion. So, once you've called that, there's no need to keep your strong reference.